# Disable Kodi notifications

Tags: kodi, openelec

I'm using Kodi within OpenElec, running from my Raspberry PI. I run this without a monitor, and control it using the [Kodi Kore](http://kodi.wiki/view/Kore) application from my tablet (music only). However sometimes Kodi freezes on the Raspberry PI because there are notifications which haven't been "okayed" on the screen. Using the tablet only, I'm unaware of these.

Is there anyway, these notifications and messages can be disabled? Or sent to the Kodi Kore application? If this functionality isn't possible, then is it part of the roadmap or a planned feature?

Example notifications could be; failed to play song, storage disconnected, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about add-on notifications?

If yes:

System -> Addon Manager -> open the left bar menu with the little arrow -> uncheck "Notifications"

If no: which notifications do you mean? Perhaps show a screenshot?